# LCD trouble during boot after update to ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

Originally I had installed ubuntu 8.04 on my Pc and it worked fine, but after an update to 10.04.2 I can't see the Ubuntu boot screen during boot, just the terminal printout. Can this be fixed?

```
Screen:  LCD model SAMSUNG SincMaster931BW
Motherboard : MSI MS-6577 v 2.1, HP/Compaq  - Xenon 4
BIOS: MSI/Award Flash BIOS Device 4 MB Flash EEPROM
CPU: Intel Pentium 4 2.8GHz/1Mb/533 mPGA478
Chipset: 854GE 
DIMM-DDR  1Gb  PC2700
Graphics Supplier: Intel Graphics Configuration in Chipset Onboard
Audio: AC'97 CODEC Device Realtek ALC650
Ethernet: Realtek RT8101L  10/100 LAN
IDE UDMA Modes ATA-66/100
Thanks from basy38-desk
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to boot in recovery mode (hold SHIFT during boot) and reconfigure your XORG?

Comment: Well, I formatted the HDD using Ext4 and finally I installed ubuntu 10.04.2 from CD and happened again. No graphic comeout after booting, the screen is black.